# Replacing an old recessed soap holder when new parts require a larger hole

Tags: shower, soap-dispenser

How can I replace a (very old) recessed soap holder when the hole dimensions are too small for modern ones?

The old one is very similar to the image shown below, but it fit in a wall cutout of 4.25" x 4.25".  All modern parts I have been able to find require a 5.25" x 5.25" wall cutout.

Cutting the wall tile to enlarge the hole is a non-starter - the risk of damaging the tile and turning this into a huge repair job is too high.

Are there more options to replace this?  I'm fine with any style as long as it gets the job done and fits in the existing hole.

[image]

Comment: The first time I ever did tile was in my own bathroom, completely unsupervised by an "adult" (i.e. someone who knew what he was doing). It's held up well for 30 years. Buy a couple of cheap tiles at your local big box store and a hack saw designed to cut tile, make a few practice cuts on your cheap throwaways, then go at it.

Answer (score 4):

Enlarging the hole would not be hard with a hand grinder and a diamond blade but since you have ruled that out, all you can do is keep searching for one that fits. We don't do shopping here but you might try some plumbing and bath supply stores since they'll have a greater selection than home stores. Keep on Googling.

Comment: Where I live there is one (local-ish) small chain that is well known for carrying ‘old’ parts, i.e. those fitting houses from the 60’s/70’s with original fittings. Find the local equivalent…

Comment: If if the hand grinder seems too risky and you would prefer a hand tool there are diamond wire hacksaw blades.

Comment: Do agree with the OP that doing that job as the first job for a novice is scary.  There probably is no place to practice cutting or extra pieces.  Doubt any of us did perfectly on our first cuts.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (small, easily shipped) might be worth spending a bit of time hunting architectural salvage places for if a vintage one would suit you.

Another option, though many will likely not be interested, (not art, too functional, too commercial, etc.) would be to have a ceramic one custom made to fit by the sort of potter who makes individual objects from clay, by hand. That will normally be the more expensive option, unless they are selling themselves short.

Comment: having one fabricated from stainless steel by a commercial sheet-metal shop is another option, but could be up-to 10 times the price of the one pictured in the question.